# Why can't you get the transfer function in time by taking inverse laplace of the transfer function in laplace?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, integrated-circuit, signal-processing, laplace-transform

In the [KD9PDP's answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/551541) in [the post below](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/551541) why can't you calculate the transfer function in time by taking the inverse Laplace transform of the transfer function in Laplace domain? 
The original post: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/551541
$$
\frac{1}{1+sRC}V_i(s)=V_o(s)\\
\frac{V_o(s)}{V_i(s)} = \frac{1}{1+sRC}\\
\frac{V_o(t)}{V_i(t)} = \frac{e^{\frac{-t}{RC}}}{RC}
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the Laplace transform of \$V_o(t)/V_i(t)\$ is not the ratio of the Laplace  transforms of \$V_o(t)\$ and \$V_i(t)\$.

A little deeper dive...

Everything is correct up to this point:

$$
\frac{V_o(s)}{V_i(s)} = \frac{1}{1+sRC} = \mathcal{L}\left( \frac{e^{\frac{-t}{RC}}}{RC} \right )
$$

and taking \$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\$ of both sides yields:

$$
  \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left( \frac{V_o(s)}{V_i(s)} \right ) = \frac{e^{\frac{-t}{RC}}}{RC} 
$$

but now you're stuck because you can't express the lefthand side in terms of \$\mathcal{L}^{-1}V_o\$ and \$\mathcal{L}^{-1}V_i\$

Answer (score 2):

Well, a general transfer function is given by:

$$\mathscr{H}\left(\text{s}\right):=\frac{\text{v}_\text{o}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\text{v}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{\text{k}}{\text{n}+\text{ms}}\tag1$$

This implies that:

$$\text{v}_\text{o}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\text{k}}{\text{n}+\text{ms}}\cdot\text{v}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)\tag2$$

Using the convolution property of the Laplace transform, we can write:

$$\text{V}_\text{o}\left(t\right)=\int_0^t\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{\text{k}}{\text{n}+\text{ms}}\right]_{\left(t-\tau\right)}\cdot\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\text{v}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)\right]_{\left(\tau\right)}\space\text{d}\tau=$$
$$\int_0^t\frac{\text{k}\exp\left(\frac{\text{n}\left(\tau-t\right)}{\text{m}}\right)}{\text{m}}\cdot\text{V}_\text{i}\left(\tau\right)\space\text{d}\tau=\frac{\text{k}}{\text{m}}\int_0^t\exp\left(\frac{\text{n}\left(\tau-t\right)}{\text{m}}\right)\cdot\text{V}_\text{i}\left(\tau\right)\space\text{d}\tau\tag3$$